# What are the "hardest" problems using polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, np-hard

Recently I read [a seminar work](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~althaus/matchings.ps.gz) which says:

> The matching algorithm [for general graphs] can be extended
>   to the weighted case, which appears to
>   be one of the "hardest" combinatorial
>   optimization problems that can be
>   solved in polynomial time.

Immediately the following question came to my mind:

**Do you know other "P-hard" problems?**

For now I would like to define P-hard as: *"A polynomial algorithm was found very late (after 1950) in the literature for that problem".* (Or how could one better define "hard" if there is already a deterministic algorithms which solves the problem in polynomial time?)

Comment: I would ask for problems with a high lower bound in P.

Comment: IMHO a bound couldn't and shouldn't compared *accross* different types of algorithms or what do you mean with lower bound?

Comment: Probably true, but it's not a very scientific question either ;-)
Lower bound: The problem has a lower bound of Omega(n**x).

Comment: yes, it is not scientific, but I learned a lot :-) and in the case of my cited "P-hard" problem the complexity has a relative low lower bound: ~O(n^3) ... and what if there are more than one dependent variables m,L, ... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually "P-complete" problems, which means that every other problem that can be computed in polynomial time can be reduced to them. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete.

Comment: Thanks! There are a lot things I can learn ... can I accept the answer from more than one?

Comment: No you can't. And you should keep your question open for about a day, so people have a chance to see it.

Answer (score 10):

[Primes is in P](http://www.ams.org/notices/200305/fea-bornemann.pdf).

Comment: +1 Because this was the first answer I thought of after reading the question.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! BTW: Does this has an effect to cryptography?

Comment: ah, ok. the "How Practial!?" section already answered this :-)

Comment: @Karussell anyway it doesn't have an effect on cryptography. Primality testing is easy. What is difficult is factoring and discrete logarithm; the basic number-theoretic public key cryptosystems depend on these (RSA -- factoring, Diffie-Hellman -- discrete logarith). The practical primality testing algorithms are probabilistic but work in practice very fast.

Answer (score 5):

Another "hard" P problem is solving "linear programming":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Algorithms

Answer (score 3):

If you want to bend the rules a bit, then [pseudo-polynomial time algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) are the "hardest" that you can solve in "polynomial time".

A classic example of a pseudo-polynomial algorithm is the `O(nW)` dynamic programming solution to the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Answer (score 2):

[The Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) which can be solved in O(n<sup>3</sup>) by the modified [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: ok very similar to the problem I mentioned ... only for bipartite graphs. BTW it is older than 1950 ;-) see wikipedia: "In 2006, it was discovered that Carl Gustav Jacobi had solved the assignment problem in the 19th century, and published posthumously in 1890 in Latin."